# Boot amination off center

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean

In using cm 10.1.3 for the Samsung galaxy tab 2 p3110 I noticed the boot animation was off center. How could I fix this?

EDIT
As discussed in comments, rotation failed. Link to unedited boot animation [here](http://www.bhoot.co.uk/view/1116-lollipop-bootlogo)

Comment: Grab the bootanimation zip file for your ROM, edit the images and flash it again?

Comment: Rotate? That failed horribly. :(

Comment: I'm confused. You rotated the image unsuccessfully?

Comment: No. I rotated them, and it brought it down to 2FPS, stopped the amination half way in.

Comment: Hmmm, if you just rotated them without disrupting the order, dimensions, or anything else there's no reason why the animation should stop. Could you edit in a link to the `zip` in your question? Then anyone who stumbles upon this could try to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sure, give me a while. May as well move this to chat too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26006/discussion-between-dan-b-and-huey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was Samsung's loveable kernel. Changing to a supported custom kernel fixed this.